# What is the proper way to display a shared info panel for a list of items?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular2-routing

I am developing a web page. This page contains a list of items on the left side, and a information panel on the right side to show some summary information specific to the selected items see below:
[image]

When one item is selected by user, the information panel's content should be updated to show the active item's content.

**My Question:**

What is the proper way to implement this:

1. Spawn one information panel per list item. Then hide/show the the information panel for the active list item.
2. Make only one information panel globally. Then update the information panel's content based on list item selection?

Because I am using Angular 2 and Bootstrap, advices specific to these libraries are appreciated. (For example, shall I use route to implement the item-click-to-summary-display? Is there a component in Bootstrap library that is specifically for such purposes? )

Comment: You only need the routing if you want to be able to have a link that will load the page with a predefined selection. If you don't need that then you can just have a "selectedItem" variable that the summary panel looks at for values. Then have the ngclick item on each list item set the selectedItem to the item being clicked.

Comment: @JosephEvans I think this will work.